Bug when logging models using Lightning Trainer, WandB and Hydra?
Our setup:
Training script using pytorch lightning Trainer & WandB Logger. Further, Hydra is used to configure the training setup (Datasets, Hyperparameters, Optimizer...)
The Model object is an instance of LightningModule and saves the hydra config (in OmegaConf type) to self.cfg
When I use
wandb_logger = WandbLogger(log_model='all', project=cfg.experiment_name, name=cfg.experiment_name)
The model artifact which is then logged to my Weights and Biases instance also contains a Run Config which is badly structured; each character of my cfg is a value of a key-value pair.
enter image description here
I suppose that the wandb logger iterates over all iterable properties the model has and loggs them separately.
As I don't want to lose the very well readable dot-notation from OmegaConf in my training script, i ask here:
Is there a way to fix this issue?
I went through the doc of WandB - I tried to find the property "Run Config" of the Model Artifact (wasn't able to find that). In general, it was not possible to find that exact badly structured config representation in any of my objects retreiveable by the Wandb Api.

Fixed already by using Box (python-box) library and converting the OmegaConf object to a dictionary using
config_dict = OmegaConf.to_container(cfg, resolve=True, throw_on_missing=True)
And then converting the config_dict to a Box object when constructing the model:
import box
class Model(L.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self,
                 cfg,
                 class_weights):
        super().__init__()

        self._cfg = box.Box(cfg)

